# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python': 'python' while running a python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

While trying to run a python script on EC2 (running ubuntu), I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "128d.py", line 9, in <module>
    "--pca_params", "./vggish_pca_params.npz"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python': 'python'
```

All the dependencies are installed. I've tested the script on my home machine (Windows 10), and it works just fine. I can see that something is wrong with python installed on the EC2 machine, probably. But I didn't manage to find an answer on the web.

Comment: What is the file you provide? Have you tried giving full path ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've fixed the problem.

Turns out, I had my python installed in a folder that was named `python3`. So, when the `suprocess.py` file tried to find `python` in `path`, it wasn't there.

I've renamed `python3` in `/usr/bin/` to python and the problem is fixed.

P.S. However, keep in mind, that it might raise some other issues. When I tried to `aws s3 cp`, it was looking for python3 instead. Maybe adding another copy of that folder as python3 would help.

Comment: As a warning to others: renaming files belonging to installed packages is generally a terrible idea, and will usually lead to worse problems than they fix.

Comment: > So, when the suprocess.py file tried to find `python` in `PATH`

Code should be using `sys.executable` to refer to the current Python interpreter's executable rather than hardcoding a string such as `python`.